# What's the connection between rank of matrix and $0$ eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My matrix B is nxn and know nothing about if diagonalizble, but I know that rank B = 1. 
Therefore the geometric multiplicity of λ=0 as an eigenvalue is n-1. 
But by knowing the rank is 1, can I say that the algebraic multiplicity is n-1 too or could it be more?

Comment: It can't be more, because if it was more, it would be the null matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking about whether the algebraic multiplicity could be *less* than $n-1$. Here's a hint. What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}1 & 0&0&0&0 &\\0&0&1&0&0&\\0&0&0&1&0&\\0&0&0&0&1&\\0&0&0&0&0&\\&&&&&\ddots\end{array}\right]?$$